# Does constant time access imply contiguous memory at some point?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, iterator, undefined-behavior

As the title says, I was wondering if **constant-time/O(1)** access to a container does imply that memory is necessarily contiguous at **some** point.
When I say contiguous I mean if pointers can be compared with **relational operators** at some point without invoking undefined behavior.

Take eg *std::deque*: it does not guarantee that all its elements are stored contiguously (i.e in the same memory array), but is it correct to say that as std::deque satisfy the requirements of a ***Random Access Iterator***, memory will be contiguous at some point independently of the implementation?

I am new to C++ so in case what I said above does not make sense: suppose I was going to implement random access iterators in C. Can

```
typedef struct random_access_iterator {
    void *pointer; /*pointer to element */
    void *block; /* pointer to the memory array
                  * so in case of comparing iterators
                  * where pointer does not point to addresses in the same array
                  * it can be used to comparisons instead*/
    /* implement other stuff */
} RandomIter;
```

be used to generically express a similar mechanism to that of C++ random access iterators (considering that even if pointer do not, block will always 
 point to addresses in the same memory array in iterators of the same container)?

EDIT: just to clarify, constant-time here is used to denote constant-time **random access**

Comment: "memory will be contiguous at some point independently of the implementation" - meaning what? contiguous memory is an implementation feature.

Comment: As I clearly stated, I want to know if that's an implication, like a empirical thing.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean constant time *random* access?

Comment: Yes, like that of C++ random access iter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Consider a fixed-size linked list like the following:

```
struct DumbCounterexample
{
    struct node
    {
        std::vector<int> items;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<node> first;
    size_t size;
    static constexpr size_t NODE_COUNT = 10;

    DumbCounterexample()
        : first{new node},
          size{0}
    {
        node* to_fill = first.get();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NODE_COUNT - 1; ++i) {
            to_fill->next.reset(new node);
            to_fill = to_fill->next.get();
        }
    }

    int& operator[](size_t i)
    {
        size_t node_num = i % NODE_COUNT;
        size_t item_num = i / NODE_COUNT;
        node* target_node = first.get();
        for (size_t n = 0; n < node_num; ++n) {
            target_node = target_node->next.get();
        }
        return target_node->items[item_num];
    }

    void push_back(int i)
    {
        size_t node_num = size % NODE_COUNT;
        node* target_node = first.get();
        for (size_t n = 0; n < node_num; ++n) {
            target_node = target_node->next.get();
        }
        target_node->items.push_back(i);
        ++size;
    }

};
```

Lookup time is constant.  It does not depend on the number of elements stored in the container (only the constant `NODE_COUNT`).

Now, this is a strange data structure, and I can't think of any legitimate reason to use it, but it does serve as a counterexample to the claim that there need be a single contiguous block of memory that would be shared by all iterators to elements in the container (i.e. the `block` pointer in your example `random_access_iterator` struct).

Comment: Thank you. Sou how would you implement such thing (iterators) in C?

Comment: Also, if it were a STL container, could it have a random access iterator at all?

Comment: I expect you would need to use vtables to implement generic iterator in C.  Every container type needs its own iterator type and its own set of functions to work on it.  C++ gets around this runtime overhead using templates.

Comment: The container in my answer could have a simple iterator that holds a pointer to the container and an index and calls `operator[]` from its `operator*`.  I think that would be enough to satisfy the requirements for RandomAccessIterator.  There are other, more efficient, ways to implement such an iterator as well, but that would be the simplest.

Comment: So that solves the problem to implement access (i.e. operator[]) but how it could be done to implement relational operators (i.e. operator<)?

Comment: You just compare the contained indices.